# What is the redis URI, when redis is used in kubernetes?

Tags: redis, kubernetes

**Objective**

I want to access the redis database in kubernetes, from a function inside ibm functions using javascript.

**Question**

How do I get the right URI, when redis is running on a Pod in Kubernetes?

**Situation**

I used this sample to setup the redis database in kubernetes [This is the link to the sample in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#creating-a-pod-to-run-a-redis-server)
I run Kuberentes inside IBM Cloud.

**Findings**

I was not able to find a answer to my question on the [redis documentation](https://redis.io/documentation)

As far as I understand by default no password configured.
Is this assumption right?

```
redis://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[CLUSTER-PUBLIC-IP]:[PORT]
```

Thanks for help ... I know this is maybe a to simple question, but currently I do not see the tree in the woods ;-)

Answer (score 7):

> As far as I understand by default no password configured.

Yes, there is no default password in that image with Redis, you are right.

If you following the instruction you mentioned, you will use a `kubectl proxy`, which will forward port of your Redis in cluster to your local machine by call `kubectl port-forward redis-master 6379:6379`.

So in that case, Redis will be available on `redis://localhost:6379` on your PC.

If you want to make it available directly from ouside of the cluster, you need to create [Service with NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport), [Service with LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer) (if you in Cloud) or simply [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service) with [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Inside a cluster, you can create Service with Cluster IP (which is actually simply Service, because it always has Cluster IP) for your Redis pod and will be available on:

`redis://[USER]:[PASSWORD]@[SERVICE-IP]:[PORT]`

Here is a good official documentation about [connecting applications with service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/).